# JavaScript initialise function

Tags: javascript, oop, object

If I created a javascript object like so:

```
Test = function(params) {
    this.test = params.test || 'element';
    this.test1 = params.test1 || '#000';
    this.test2 = params.test2;
    this.test3 = params.test3;

    //need a neat little initialise function to create some html elements here! 
}

var test = new Test({test: "#CCC", test1: [0, 1, 3], test2: [0, 1, 3]});
```

How would I then create a proper initialise function that would run when an instance of that object was created like above.

Would I simple make a function and then call it, or is there a way to make a function that runs on its own when an object instance is created.

Comment: Why can't you just do it in the constructor you already have?

Comment: You could create a function `Test.prototype.init_html_` and call it from the constructor. If it is very simply code, put it in the constructor, that's what it's there for.

Comment: This really all depends on what it is you're trying to do.  I mean...  ...you could `function init( obj ) { obj[0] = document.createElement("div"); };` but what is that accomplishing, exactly?  What is it that your `init` is trying to do?  What do you want the end result of `var test` to be?  And what do you want to be able to ***DO*** with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your constructor already *is* a function, you can just place the code there. Technically speaking, the constructor is *the* initialisation function for objects.

> Would I simple make a function and then call it, or is there a way to make a function that runs on its own when an object instance is created.

That depends. Can you reuse the html element creation code somewhere else than in the constructor? Then put it in a separate function (possibly on the prototype) and call that from the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You already have an initialise function, that's where the variables are being defined. Just do stuff there, and it will happen when you create an instance of the object.